# How to disable deceleration in OrbitControls?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to set up OrbitControls in my project (https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-demo-forked-hysd8).

While getting closer to maxDistance, the speed of zooming decelerates. Zooming become slower and slower.

It is possible to disable the deceleration and make zooming speed constant?

Comment: Nope, this requires a custom modification of `OrbitControls`.

Comment: @Mugen87 Would the modification be complicated?

Comment: If you only need to scroll along a timeline I would not use `OrbitControls` at all. Instead I suggest you modify the position of the camera based on a `wheel`/`touch` event handler.